# ruby: representing binary string as Bignum

Tags: ruby, pack, bignum, unpack

I need to have a numeric representation of a binary string of arbitrary length. This seemingly trivial task unexpectedly turned out to be complex.  The best I could come up with so far is

```
string.unpack('H*')[0].to_i(16)
```

but this operation lacks reversibility, because unpack may return a leading zero in the highest nibble:

```
['ABC'].pack('H*') == ['0ABC'].pack('H*') # false
```

Now I need to check if I got even number of nibbles after converting from integer, pad with zero if needed etc.  It's all good and clear, but I just can't believe this must be so convoluted.

Update with example:

```
s = "\x01\x1D\x9A".force_encoding 'binary' # "\x01\x1D\x9A"
s.unpack('H*') # ["011d9a"]
s.unpack('H*')[0].to_i(16) # 73114
```

Now let's decode:

```
s.unpack('H*')[0].to_i(16).to_s(16) # "11d9a" — notice that leading zero is gone
[s.unpack('H*')[0].to_i(16).to_s(16)].pack('H*') # "\x11\xD9\xA0"
[s.unpack('H*')[0].to_i(16).to_s(16)].pack('H*') == s # false, obviously
```

In other words, we failed to decode to the same value we started with.

Comment: Give a sample input and expected output. Your post is not descriptive enough with only the code you wrote.

Comment: what's wrong with just: string.to_i(16) ?

Comment: string.to_(16) converts a string of hexadecimal digits, not an arbitrary string of bits.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have zero knowledge in Ruby, though have an idea which you could check...

May be .to_s(16) method converts to string which have different default encoding and may be this matters when you make string comparison after .pack('H*')?
May be this will work:
[s.unpack('H*')[0].to_i(16).to_s(16)].pack('H*').force_encoding 'binary' == s

Otherwise it's difficult to imagine how nibble with leading zero could convert to string byte which is different from same string byte but converted from hex nibble without zero.